# Не запускается .bashrc

Tags: bash, linux

Я создал файл в $HOME/.bashrc (ибо его там не было) внес команды, а он не запускается, то есть не вносит все настройки, что я туда внес. Если эти команды просто ввожу в консоль все работает.

(Хостинг не мой)

Comment: для отладки .bashrc полезно запускать bash -x и смотреть вывод

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема решена.Нужно в файлике $HOME/.bash_profile прописать . "$HOME/.bashrc"И все )